# Mpipeline cannot be used when configuring a ChangeStreamCursor

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
var client = new MongoClient("<My connection string>");
var watchedDatabaseNames = new List<string> { "DB1", "DB2" };
var options = new ChangeStreamOptions { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };
var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()
    .Match(change => watchedDatabaseNames.Contains(change.DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName));
var cursor = client.Watch(pipeline, options);
```

> Throws System.NotSupportedExceptions: 'Serializer for
> MongoDB.Driver.DatabaseNamespace must implement
> IBsonDocumentSerializer to be used with LINQ'

at the last line above.

I simply want to get notified by a Change Stream, but only for documents in certain databases.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try use raw MQL text instead typed form: `new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<BsonDocument>>()                 .Match("{ Filtering MQL query : 1 }");`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, however, I am not able to see how I can query on the mentioned DatabaseNamespace.DatabaseName property (sorry for my lack of mongo experience).
Could you please be a bit more specific in your solution to my requirement?